EF Core: How can I use TPH with a read-only discriminator entity property?
Anyone know if it's possible to have a readonly property that's used as a discriminator field when using TPH inheritance. For instance, suppose you have something like this:
public enum EntityType{
  EntityA,
  EntityB
}

public abstract class Base{
  public abstract EntityType EntityType{ get; }

  // other properties/methods
}

public class Entity1{
  public override EntityType EntityType => EntityType.EntityA;

  // other properties
}

// more derived classes

Once more, it's dairly easy to map this sort of thing with NHibernate, but EF Core doesn't like it.
So, does the property really needs to have a setter for this to work?
EDIT1 Following the suggestions on the comments, I've updated the types and replaced the  computed property with a readonly property:
public class Entity1{
  public override EntityType EntityType {get; } =  EntityType.EntityA;

  // other properties
}


I'm also showing the mappings I have:
public sealed class BaseTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Base>{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<base> builder) {
    builder.HasDiscriminator(g => g.EntityType)
           .HasValue<Entity1>(EntityType.EntityA)
           ....;
    builder.Property(g => g.EntityType).HasColumnName("EntityDbColumn");
  }
}

however, this still doesn't solve the issue and I get an error which says something like: "No backing field could be found for property 'base.EntityType' and the property does not have a setter.
What am I still missing?
Thanks.
Thanks

Sure it is. And how does that info help? Thanks.

EF can handle read-only properties, but  EntityType => EntityType.EntityA; isn't one. It's a calculated property. Besides, you don't need a discriminator property at all. You only need a column in the table, where EF itself will store the type. That doesn't have to be a property,

how does that info help it means that multiple misconceptions caused code that doesn't even do what you assume and makes things harder for everyone. Why do you want a visible discriminator property in the first place? And if there's a valid reason, why not use a plain old property that's set to a specific value in the constructor? If you wanted to query by type, .OfType<Entity1>() does the job. If you want to process results by type, pattern matching on type is far cleaner than an enum that may be out of sync with the types, and doesn't ensure completeness

In any case, there's no point in EntityType => EntityType.EntityA;. EF itself will write the stored discriminator value to it, even if it's truly read-only. All that's needed is public EntityType EntityType{ get; } or public EntityType EntityType{ get; private set;}. The difference in these is that EntityType{ get; private set;} is mapped by convention while EntityType{ get; } requires explicit model configuration. The reason for this is explained in the read-only property docs

The TPH docs explained that the discriminator column is mapped as a shadow property by default. That means that if the actual value is needed at any point and the object type isn't enough (why??) the shadow property can be accesses through the change tracker with context.Entry(myBlog).Property("Discriminator").CurrentValue

I'll give it a go and I'll come back with my findings. thanks.

Still not working...I've added more information to the post. thanks again.

You didn't do what I wrote at all, so there's no wonder nothing changed.  There's absolutely no reason at all to make the property abstract and override it. There's no reason to even have that property.

Instead for trying to make EF work the way you think it should, remove all extra coding (ie remove that property completely) and let EF work using its own conventions. This way you will always have working code to fall back to as you experiment. Can you query specific types, or make a polymorphic query? Once that works, only then try to read the shadow discriminator property. If that works, then add a real read-only string discriminator property. Once that works, change it to an enum

Hello again. I'm not disputing that. The thing is that this is legacy code which has that property so that NH can work properly. I can remove the abstract/override and use type checking at run time. Thanks. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

It's not just that EF isn't NHibernate. To solve complex problems you have to break them down and isolate the pieces. You have to see how EF does work, preferably in a separate small project, and make small working changes until you reach the outcome you want.

Yes, you're right. Even though EF has come a long way and is able to manage pratically all of the scenarios I have in this app, it's quite interesting to see that NH still has the upper hand when you're coming from the OO side (ie, requires far less changes to the OO model just to persist it in a db). Once more, thanks for your help.

That's not what I wrote or mean. NH isn't better in this example. The class property is an artifact, not a feature and you still haven't explained why you want it. As for less changes to the OO model ALL ORMs are bad at it. At the most basic level, that's simply because OO and Relational are different, with OO closer to hierarchical/Doc DBs like MongoDB. No ORM can bridge that gap without causing problems. On top of that, the best model for storage is different from the best business model, which is different from the resource model and that from the API model.

In 2006 Ted Neward described ORMs as The Vietnam of Computer Science. Back then Hibernate was king and EF years in the future. LINQ made querying a bit easier, and even removed some of the pain around reporting queries. But things like inheritance rarely map well to REST APIs or  JSON. That holds even in GraphQL or OData, which do have inheritance. What programmers want are polymorphic queries, not inheritance. It's easier to implement these using eg JS's open type model or TypeScript's summary types

The NH observation is my opinion, not yours. And yes, you're right: we still need to change lots of things when using an ORM. However, this migration shows that EF still requires more changes than NH. For instance, it seems incapable of persisting a primitive collection to a separate table or,when using TPH, to map  different derived type's properties to the same column. Anyway, it's what it is, so if you want to use it, you'll have to adapt to it. Thanks again.

@LuisAbreu, you cannot =( https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15530
